# Git stash fails 'error: unable to resolve reference refs/stash: No such file or directory'

Tags: git, git-stash

Git pull command is working fine, but git stash is giving the following error:

```
$git stash
error: unable to resolve reference refs/stash: No such file or directory
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/stash'.
Cannot save the current status
```

How do i resolve this so that i don't loose my changes?

Comment: Does your user have write permissions in the `.git`/`.git/refs` directory?

Comment: What OS and what git version are you using?

Comment: git version 1.7.9.5, Linux OS.  .git and .git/refs have read and execute permissions

Comment: @schipitch: You must be able to write to the directory, otherwise you cannot create files

Comment: @knittl i have been using git for quite some time, and it has been working with the same permissions, it is only today that this error occurred.

Comment: I deleted the stash file in .git/logs/refs and .git/refs, now it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @schipitch: Maybe you have issued a git command as another user (e.g. root). This could result in wrong permissions for your user.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was having a very similar issue, after a corrupted filesystem.

The solution was to remove the file or directory at .git/logs/refs/stash

After deleting the file or directory, please use git stash to create a new ref, and that's all.

This will delete any stash you might have, so please be careful.

```
git stash
error: refs/stash does not point to a valid object!
rm -r .git/logs/refs/stash
git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: e1d74d8 fixing get_thumbnail_list
```

Comment: Yes, i did similar thing, and this problem didn't arise again. Thanks

Comment: on git version 2.6.2 the file can be found at: .git/refs/stash

Comment: Where do the files/commits/objects live if you have multiple stashes on multiple branches? and multiple stashes sharing a single parent commit?

Answer (score 20):

I had to delete following file also to get it working.

```
rm -f .git/refs/stash
```

Comment: Computer crashed during git stash operation and seemingly I lost all my stashes. TL;DR: deleting only this bad `.git/refs/stash` allowed me to recover my stash list.

In case it helps anyone else: My stash seemed ok in `.git/logs/refs/stash` (so didn't want to delete this). 

Followed first step of: https://dev.to/meduzen/recover-a-lost-git-stash-in-two-steps-569

where the `git fsck` command reported:
`error: refs/stash: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: bad ref for refs/stash`

but stopped here and did another search to find this SO answer :D.

Comment: Didn't work fully - seems like all it did was allow `git stash list` to return, but trying to run `git stash apply` doesn't work at all. 
`warning: Log for ref refs/stash unexpectedly ended on Tue, 17 Dec 2019 22:27:25 +0900.`

Guess I have to abandon this repo and start again. Other git operations don't seem to work properly either.

Comment: I had to delete `.git/refs/stash.lock` as well. After that `git stash` started to work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the stash and add new stash folder if the problem still remained after remove the stash:

`rm -r .git/logs/refs/stash`

`mkdir .git/logs/refs/stash`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed mine. Had some funky stashed objects that were causing my problem.
**NOTE:** Had to include the stash.lock in order to get it to work.

```
rm -r .git/logs/refs/stash .git/logs/refs/stash.lock
```