# No list shown in 'git stash list'

Tags: git, github

I just recently cloned a repo and made changes to it. I pulled the latest commits from a branch called *dev* but before that I stashed my changes with a message using this command:

```
git stash save "mymessage"
```

giving me a message after that saying:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 186:
>   c:/Users/Mine/source/repos/My Branch/ .git/logs/refs/stash: No such
>   file or directory Saved working directory and index state On dev:
>   mymessage HEAD is now at 1413c2 Latest Commit.

then used

```
git pull
```

just that. The pull was fine. My local repo was now updated but then when I tried to apply my stash. No list was found when I checked. Even after using

```
git stash list
```

nothing appears but another command line. When I to try use

```
git stash apply
```

it gives me a message saying:

> ref/stash@{0} is not a valid reference

I've done this a couple times before from a another local repo and it's doing fine. This is the first time I've encountered this from a new local repo.

Comment: What's your question now?

Comment: how can  I find my stash and apply it? @Basilevs

Comment: It's gone. The original stash never happened, as per your earlier message.

Comment: You can also try `git stash pop`.  If that also results in nothing happening, then you rest assured that you have no stashes available.

Comment: Oh nooo! but I was able to pull the latest commits. What happened then to the changes I made? :( @mprat

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480174/git-stash-fails-error-unable-to-resolve-reference-refs-stash-no-such-file-or

Comment: @germikee Pulling and stashing aren't related - the links in the answer below might have some insight about dropped stashes. In general, best practice is to commit the changes to another branch before pulling so you don't lose changes.

Comment: Damn.... is that so. Bummer! thanks for the replies @mprat

Answer (score 2):

You won't find your stash, because you don't have any. Git failed to create one for you, and properly reported the problem, but you've opted to ignore this.

Try to look in `git reflog` - a commit created for stashing might still be there. [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git)

Comment: the thing is, I didnt commit my changes. I just stashed them. Is there no other way for me to find my stash? :(

Comment: @germikee, stashing creates Git objects that should show up in the reflog if they exist.

Comment: well i dont see mine. tsk. thanks for the replies anyway guys :)