# Git stash error "Cannot save the current status"

Tags: git

I'm getting this error when running "git stash"

```
Cannot save the current status
```

with no other information.

Why is that?

Comment: What does git status say?

Comment: "On branch master    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.    nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the solution here: [Git stash fails 'error: unable to resolve reference refs/stash: No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480174/git-stash-fails-error-unable-to-resolve-reference-refs-stash-no-such-file-or)

```
rm -f .git/refs/stash .git/refs/stash.lock
```

That fixed it

Comment: I had to delete `.git/refs/stash.lock` as well. After that `git stash` started to work well.

Comment: i got solution from your link, but the file your removed, not just that , my issue got resolve with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409320/4811421 answer from your link

Answer (score 13):

In my case, `.git/refs/stash` was owned by `root`.

Simply running `chown -R <user>:<group> .git` (Linux) fixed it.

Note that you might only need to `chown -R <user>:<group> .git/refs/stash`, though.

Replace `<user>` and `<group>` with your user name and main group.

Comment: This was precisely my issue too. A precommit hook inside a docker container had changed the owner.

Answer (score 7):

I solve this problem by `git stash clear`.

Answer (score 4):

For me,

```
cd .git/
sudo chmod -R 777 *
sudo chown -R owner:owner *
git add . && git stash
```

Worked

Comment: It is more safety: sudo chmod -R ug+w .

Answer (score 2):

You get this error sometime when you are in mid of a conflict. You will get more information if you check git status and see if you are in mid of a merge conflict resolution.

You can either abort the merge:
If you don't want to consider your previous merge (you are sure and you would lose the history information associated with the merge), you can abort then using

```
git merge --abort
```

Or reset your git state to original HEAD:

```
git reset ORIG_HEAD
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: "git merge --abort" gives me "fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).". If I reset to head, and change I single file to try to stash, I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had Visual Studio using git and was trying to stash using the command line.
Closing Visual Studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but this may help Mac users.

If you are copying files from Time Machine manually, instead of restoring them through Time Machine, it'll add [ACLs](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/) to everything, which can mess up your permissions.

For example, the section in [this article](http://dreamlight.com/how-to-fix-mac-os-x-file-permissions/) that says "How to Fix Mac OS X File Permissions" shows that "everyone" has custom permissions, which messes it all up:

Bad permissions, from http://dreamlight.com/how-to-fix-mac-os-x-file-permissions

You need to remove the ACLs from those directories/files. [This Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/299912) goes into it, but here's the command:

sudo chmod -RN .

Then you can make sure your directories and files have the proper permissions. I use 750 for directories and 644 for files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in Windows by right clicking on the shortcut to Git Bash and choosing "Run as administrator" before I run `git stash`.

I can verify that running Git Fork as administrator also solves this problem if using Git Fork to stash, so there is a good chance it will solve it in other git tools such as Git for Windows or Sourcetree.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
git reset --mixed
```

and then

```
git stash
```

before pull.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because some files changed their permissions (in ubuntu). I fixed it by running the command git stash with "sudo"

```
sudo git stash
```

I hope you can fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other solutions with no luck, but this worked for me:

```
rm -f .git/refs/stash.lock
```

and then

```
git gc
```